# Replacing Value in Vector that are greater than x

Tags: replace

I am collecting data from a number of different reports and some are using measurements on a different factor base.

So the vector looks like this:

```
a <- c("1.5", "1.8", "2.1", "3.4", "4100", "5.1", "6.3", "7.9", "8700", "8.9", "9.0", "11.7")
```

I'd like to divide the numbers which are greater than 100 by 1000.

Looking at another example I've tried

```
a[a>100] <- a/1000
```

But that doesn't seem to store the correct result. Any advice greatfully received.

Answer (score 0):

What language you use for this?
In most dynamical language you can do something like this

```
a.map({ item -> if (item > 100) item / 1000 else item })
```

You need to adjust syntax, but generally it'll look like this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm working in R, that doesn't seem to do it. I get an error "Error in a.map({ : could not find function "a.map" "

Comment: here is a link for map in R: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.3/topics/map